# How to access the Nagios web interface after successful installation?

Tags: networking, ip, nagios

I just installed Nagios Core on an Ubuntu virtual environment, apparently successfully. But when I try to access the Nagios web interface with the IP address gotten from the `ifconfig` command, it opens the Apache Ubuntu default page. How can I access the Nagios web interface?

Comment: (1) What do you mean by “virtual environment”?  Is it a virtual machine?  If so, what hypervisor? (2) *How* are you trying to access the nagios web interface, and from where? … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: finally able to access. i just had to write ip-address/nagios

Answer (score 0):

The OP has reported that
the solution is to access `<IP_address>/nagios`.